# why redis store memory data only in little endian?

Tags: redis

When I read redis source code , I found redis store memory data only in little endian. When these data are fetched, they have to be converted to the local machine byte order. Such  as in  ziplist.c :

```
static int64_t zipLoadInteger(unsigned char *p, unsigned char encoding) {
    int16_t i16;
    int32_t i32;
    int64_t i64, ret = 0;
    if (encoding == ZIP_INT_8B) {
        ret = ((int8_t*)p)[0];
    } else if (encoding == ZIP_INT_16B) {
        memcpy(&i16,p,sizeof(i16));
        memrev16ifbe(&i16);
        ret = i16;
    } //......
    return ret;
}
```

I think the most effective way to store memory data in the local machine format(either in LE or BE), and when have to write data into disk or read them from disk, then the data can be converted to the certain format. Because data operations in memory are more often than operations in disk, so I think the way in redis is not so effective.

Or I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a strategy, but on the other hand:

- I'm pretty sure 99% of Redis production deployments run on Intel/AMD boxes (i.e. little endian boxes). So in practice, it has little impact.
- using the same memory representation to store data in memory and on disk is useful to keep the dump time low (and therefore decrease the overhead of copy-on-write memory). Because of the fork of the background save process and copy-on-write, the longer the dump, the more wasted memory. By using the same representation for ziplist, Redis RDB functions can just dump the ziplist content to the file, without having to parse it, saving many CPU cache misses.
- the RDB dump mechanism may be used even if another persistency mechanism is chosen, because it is also used to initialize slaves. Its performance is therefore critical.

Comment: I can write to or read from data from disk in the same byte order as they are in memory. That is bad for machines with different byte order, but it is rare in practice, and you can save a byte order flag in disk file and avoid errors. Handling byte order is so cumbersome!